Syzkaller report does not make sense
I'm looking at this syzkaller report: https://groups.google.com/g/syzkaller-bugs/c/FvPFh7-dtx4/m/7Yoy6KSkAAAJ?pli=1
It finds a crash caused by some commit.
After submitting some patches, syzkaller finds that a particular patch fixes the crash.
Here is the patch. It does not touch anything except forcing CONFIG_XARRAY_MULTI:
--- a/fs/Kconfig
+++ b/fs/Kconfig
@@ -279,6 +279,7 @@ endif # HUGETLBFS
 
  config HUGETLB_PAGE
  def_bool HUGETLBFS
+ select XARRAY_MULTI

  config HUGETLB_PAGE_OPTIMIZE_VMEMMAP
  def_bool HUGETLB_PAGE

However looking at the initial config https://syzkaller.appspot.com/x/.config?x=bb39fe85d254f638 the CONFIG_XARRAY_MULTI was enabled anyway (and the configs used originally and with the fix are identical).
Does this mean that the patch is falsely detected as a working fix?
Or is it a reporting bug, and Syzkaller actually used different configs than reported?

Among others the mail started with syzbot suspects this issue was fixed by commit:. And your Q puts it this way: syzkaller finds that a particular patch fixes the crash. Do you see the difference?

Yes, I understand the difference.
I'm trying to understand if it's a heisenbug or reporting bug in syzkaller.

I do not understand why you call it a bug. English is correct, there is no inconsistency. Most likely the fix is a series of the changes that the last one, which was reported, is the trigger to make syzcaller happy. I think you are looking into a wrong place. You should go to the kernel Guy history and study the evolution of the bug (reported originally) and its fix(es).
